# Changing Border Color When Incorrect Input With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I'm working on a form that is supposed to validate the input in several textboxes when the user clicks the "submit" button. If any of the required boxes are left blank or have an incorrect type of input or format, the border of those textboxes is supposed to turn red and return to the normal color when the requirements are met.

For example, a phone number is either supposed to be 7 or 10 digits long, if the user enters a six digit number like (123456), the border around this field should turn red, when the user enters one more number, like (1234567), the border should go back to it's regular color immediately, without the user having to click the "submit" button again.

How my code is written, the border does turn red when the user enters too few numbers, however, the submit button must be clicked for the border to go back to its original color. Is there a way to change the color back without the button being clicked a second time?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 4</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                border:2px solid red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            Phone Number:<input type="text" id="phone">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                return checkPhone();
            }

            function checkPhone() {
                var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
                var phoneNum = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
                if(phoneNum.length > 6 && phoneNum.length < 11) {   
                    return true;
            } 
                else if(phoneNum.length < 7 || phoneNum.length > 10) {
                    //document.getElementById("phone").className = document.getElementById("phone").className + " error";
                    //document.getElementById("phone").className = document.getElementById("phone").className.replace(" error", "");
                document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor="red";

                return false;

                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should look at the javascript plugin "Parsley" (http://parsleyjs.org/)

Comment: Are you able to use JQuery or a validation library?

Comment: No, I can't use JQuery, our professor has told us when we go over that later in the semester we're going to want to kill him because it would've made all of these projects so much easier haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a user submits the form with invalid data, you can attach `onkeyup` event listener into a input field, and everythime a user types something into the field, the form will be validated

```
document.getElementById("phone").onkeyup = validateForm;
```

I wrote `once a user submits the form` on purpose, since you do not want to fool your visitor by knowing that he typed only one character and he is getting validation error. (he is about to type 5 more characters)

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project 4</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .error {
            border:2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        Phone Number:<input type="text" id="phone">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //at first, we define a variable stating that an event listener has been attached onto the field
    var validatePhoneOnKeyUpAttached = false;

        function validateForm() {

            //then, we attach the event listened to the field after the submit, if it has not been done so far
            if(!validatePhoneOnKeyUpAttached) {
                document.getElementById("phone").onkeyup = checkPhone;
                validatePhoneOnKeyUpAttached = true;
            }

            return checkPhone();
        }

        function checkPhone() {
            var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
            var phoneNum = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
            if(phoneNum.length > 6 && phoneNum.length < 11) {   
                document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor="transparent";//and you want to remove invalid style
                return true;
        } 
            else if(phoneNum.length < 7 || phoneNum.length > 10) {
                //document.getElementById("phone").className = document.getElementById("phone").className + " error";
                //document.getElementById("phone").className = document.getElementById("phone").className.replace(" error", "");
            document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor="red";

            return false;

            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually answers a question I was about to ask on one of the other comments.

Comment: I am having some trouble figuring out where this should go in my code since it is occurring after the submit button has been clicked?

Comment: One more thing, you want to remove the invalid style before returning true to let the user know, he has done some good job `document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor="transparent"`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `onkeyup` handler for input field:

```
<input type="text" id="phone" onkeyup="checkPhone()" />
```

and also make `checkPhone` function remove `error` class if input is valid:

```
function checkPhone() {

    var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    var phoneNum = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

    if (phoneNum.length > 6 && phoneNum.length < 11) {
        document.getElementById("phone").className = '';
        return true;
    } 
    else if (phoneNum.length < 7 || phoneNum.length > 10) {
        document.getElementById("phone").className = 'error';
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bcxLz4wh/

Answer (score 0):

Use the blur event of your input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="phone" onblur="validateForm();">
```

The blur event runs when you control loses the focus. If you need something more immediate you will need to use the keyup event.